# How to get all logged in user id in buddypress

Tags: buddypress, users

I want to get all buddypress logged in user's ID.
for that sake i am using

```
$bp->loggedin_user->id
```

But this is not helping.. Please help me to get all logged in user id.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `$bp->loggedin_user->id` will only give you a single id, of the *current* logged in user. 
btw - it also requires use of the `$bp global`.
You don't need to use that global. Use `bp_loggedin_user_id()` instead.

BuddyPress does not track logged in users. It does not use sessions. 
It does use timestamps in the database to indicate recent activity. 
So you could use custom sql to return user ids. 
For example:

```
function shahid_get_recent_active() {
    global $wpdb;

    $time = time() - (60 * 10); // current time minus 10 minutes
    $cutoff = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $time);

    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_activity WHERE type = 'last_activity' AND date_recorded > '$cutoff' " ); 
    var_dump( $user_ids );

}
add_action( 'bp_ready', 'shahid_get_recent_active' );
```

`$user_ids` will be an array.